# How to keep the Dialog box open on a Activity while the activity is being refreshed (Changing theme of the app)?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity, android-dialog

I have a `Settings.kt` activity which have a theme changing feature for my app.
On clicking the theme option a `themeDialog` box pops up on the screen and with the switch, theme can be changed as shown in the pic below.
[image]
And now to reflect those changes on the `Settings.kt` activity as well as on the `themeDialog` I am refreshing the `Settings.kt` activity with the help of intent and as a result of that theme is changing properly but the `themeDialog` is closing simultaneously as the activity is refreshed.

So I am asking for a way to keep the dialog open while the theme of the `Settings.kt` activity and `themeDialog` box updates.

**Here's my code:**

`Settings.kt` activity

```
class Settings : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var settingsRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var settingsAdapter: SettingsAdapter
    private lateinit var sharedPrefForNightMode: SharedPrefForNightMode

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        sharedPrefForNightMode = SharedPrefForNightMode(this)
        if (sharedPrefForNightMode.loadNightModeState()) {
            setTheme(R.style.DarkTheme)
        } else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        settingsAdapter = SettingsAdapter(this)
        settingsRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.settings_recycler_view)
        settingsRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        settingsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
        settingsRecyclerView.adapter = settingsAdapter
    }

    override fun finish() {
        super.finish()
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    }
    override fun onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
        val intent = Intent(this,Dashboard::class.java)
        intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }
}
```

`SettingsAdapter.kt`- In this adapter I've a function `theme(context:Context)` which creates my `themeDialog` and `restartSettings()` function refreshes the `Settings.kt` activity:

```
class SettingsAdapter(private val mContext: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SettingsAdapter.SettingsViewHolder>() {    
private fun theme(context: Context) {
            val themeDialog = Dialog(context)
            themeDialog.setContentView(R.layout.theme_popup)
            themeDialog.setCancelable(false)
            themeDialog.show()
            val themeTitle = themeDialog.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.theme_title)
            val closeTheme = themeDialog.findViewById<Button>(R.id.close_theme)
            closeTheme.setOnClickListener {
                themeDialog.dismiss()
            }
            val switch = themeDialog.findViewById<Switch>(R.id.dark_mode_switch)
            if(sharedPrefForNightMode.loadNightModeState()) {
                switch.isChecked = true
                themeTitle.text = "Disable Night Mode"
            }
            switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, _ ->
                if (switch.isChecked) {
                    sharedPrefForNightMode.setNightModeState(true)
                    themeTitle.text = "Disable Night Mode"
                    restartSettings()
                } else {
                    sharedPrefForNightMode.setNightModeState(false)
                    themeTitle.text = "Enable Night Mode"
                    restartSettings()
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun restartSettings() {
            mContext.startActivity(Intent(mContext, Settings::class.java))
            (mContext as Activity).overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout)
            mContext.finish()
            mContext.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout)
        }
}
```

Comment: If you need whole code for `SettingsAdpater` let me know I've just posted the functions which are concerned to this question

Comment: A `Dialog` is owned by an `Activity` instance. You are destroying and recreating the activity, so that will destroy the `Dialog`. You will need to recreate the `Dialog` yourself in the new `Activity` instance.

Comment: Yeah but that won't hold the dialog box on the activity while it's being refreshed

Comment: Then you will need to do something that does not involve destroying and recreating your activity to affect your desired changes.

Comment: you should share setTheme function

Comment: Consider using ViewModel in Android. It keeps the instance of your Activity alive even if the system is recreating your Activity.

Comment: You mean creating the dialog box in ViewModel for the desired activity?